# Unit ball of Minkowski functional

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, origin-symmetric and convex set with nonempty interior. Minkowski functional of $K$ is the function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $$||x||_K:=\inf \{t>0: \space x/t \in K\}.$$
I need to show that the unit ball of this normed space is $K$ itself.

I've tried to google it but I didn't find any clearifications. Most of the articles just state is as truth ([http://www.math.cmu.edu/~ttkocz/teaching/1819/asympt-conv-geom-notes.pdf](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ettkocz/teaching/1819/asympt-conv-geom-notes.pdf), pg. 13 ). Is there a proof or an explanation for this?

Comment: Just use the definition of $||x||_K$ and prove the two inclusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|x\|_{K} =1\iff \inf\{t>0:x/t\in K\} = 1\iff x \in K$ since $K$ is closed.

Assume $x\not\in K$ with $\|x\|_{K}=1$. Then $x/t\in K$ for all $0<t<1$. Let $x_k = x/(1-k^{-1})$. Then $\|x_k-x_{k'}\|_{K} = \|\left((1-k^{-1})^{-1} - (1 - k'^{-1})^{-1}\right)x\|_{K} = \left((1-k^{-1})^{-1} - (1 - k'^{-1})^{-1}\right)$ and this can be made arbitrarily small. So $x_k$ converges with each $x_k\in K$ and its limit point is clearly $x$. Since $K$ is closed, $x\in K$.

There are some details to be filled in but this gets the point across.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to write $\|x\| = \inf \{ t >0 | x \in tK \}$.

The key result here is that if ${1 \over t}x \in K$ for some $t>0$ then
${1 \over s}x \in K$ for any $s \ge t$.

If $\|x\|\le 1$ then for $t > 1$ we have $\|x\| < {1 \over t}$ and so ${1 \over t}x \in K$. Since $K$ is closed, letting $t \to 1$ shows that $x \in K$.

If $x \in K$, then $\|x\| \le 1$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in K$, then obviously $x/1 \in K,$ so $\|x\|_K\leq 1$.

For the other direction, it probably would be best split into two cases:

- If $\|x\|_K < 1$ then that means there is some $0 < t < 1$ such that $x/t \in K$.  Since $K$ is origin symmetric, $-x/t \in K$, and since $K$ is convex, $$x = \left(\frac{1+t}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{x}{t} + \left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{x}{t}\right) \in K$$
- If $\|x\|_K = 1$, then either $x=x/1 \in K$ (in which case there's nothing to prove) or $x/t_n \in K$ for some $t_n \downarrow 1$, in which case $x/t_n \to x \in K$ since $K$ is closed.

---

One last thing to note: Showing $\|x\| \leq 1 \iff x \in K$ didn't use the assumption that $K$ has nonempty interior.  This assumption is required to show $\|\cdot\|_K$ is actually a norm.  Without it, we could have e.g. $\|x\|_K = \infty$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$